# Having issue on second iteration after catching error in input

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Just learning python, and trying to make a game of Hangman. 
I'm having an issue when running the program, where if I run through it without trying to throw it off (ex. input "enter" and input "2") then it gives me a random word of difficulty I'm asking for.

If I try to throw it off, (ex. input "enter", input "12", input "3") it returns "None"

I've been trying to figure it out, printing different variables in different locations to see what's off, but I can't find anything.

I'd appreciate any help I can get.
Any other input welcome as well.

[wordbank file](https://github.com/KMac1290/Files/tree/master)

```
import random
import math

# Random Word Generator
with open('wordbank.csv') as f:
    file = f.read().split('\n')
    word_list = list(file)


def max_letters(x):
    max_length = 0
    for words in x:
        if len(str(words)) >= max_length:
            max_length = len(str(words))
    return max_length


def word_selector(x):
    diff = input("What difficulty would you like? Type a difficulty of 1 - 3 and press 'Enter':  ")
    diff_list = []
    diff_var = math.ceil((max_letters(word_list) / 3))
    if diff == "1" or diff == "2" or diff == "3":
        for words in x:
            length = len(str(words))
            if diff == "1":
                if 0 < length <= diff_var:
                    diff_list.append(str(words))
            elif diff == "2":
                if diff_var < length <= (diff_var * 2):
                    diff_list.append(str(words))
            elif diff == "3":
                if (diff_var * 2) < length:
                    diff_list.append(str(words))
        return random.choice(diff_list)
    else:
        print("That's not an option... Difficulties are 1 - 3. Try again.")
        word_selector(word_list)


def start_hangman():
    start = input("Press 'Enter' to start!\n")
    if start == "":
        print(word_selector(word_list))  # Will eventually be hangman
    else:
        print("What are you doing??? Just press enter!")
        start_hangman()


start_hangman()
```

Comment: can't run your code without wordbank.csv.

Comment: I have it. As stated, program works if I don't try to throw it off.

Comment: if you are raising an exception then you must mention customized error.

Comment: No error. It's still outputting a result. The result is "None". (not one of the words in wordbank.csv, file only has words of five letters or more)

Comment: You didn't return anything in that section of your code, you just printed something. Try `return "That's not an option... Difficulties are 1 - 3. Try again.")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function back, which is called *recursion*. It can be pretty confusing. Let's say a bad input, `12` is entered. The function `word_selector()` will execute the `else` statement, which calls the function back:

```
def word_selector(x):
    (...)
    else:
        word_selector(word_list) # <-- we are here
```

The function then asks again for input, let's say this time a valid input is entered, `3`. It will then correctly return a word, let's say  `apple`. So now, the function returned `apple`, but we are back at where the function was called from.

```
def word_selector(x):
    (...)
    else:
        "apple" # because the function call returned "apple".
```

As you can see now, the `else` condition simply says "apple", without returning anything or assigning it to a value. Since the function does not return anything, `python` makes it return `None`, which is like a null/undefined value. This is why you are getting your error.

As a fix, I believe you have to move your error-checking and input getting code out of `word_selector()` to the `start_hangman()` loop. For example, this works as intended:

```
import random
import math

# Random Word Generator
with open('wordbank.csv') as f:
    file = f.read().split('\n')
    word_list = list(file)


def max_letters(x):
    max_length = 0
    for words in x:
        if len(str(words)) >= max_length:
            max_length = len(str(words))
    return max_length


def word_selector(x, diff):
    diff_list = []
    diff_var = math.ceil((max_letters(word_list) / 3))
    for words in x:
        length = len(str(words))
        if diff == "1":
            if 0 < length <= diff_var:
                diff_list.append(str(words))
        elif diff == "2":
            if diff_var < length <= (diff_var * 2):
                diff_list.append(str(words))
        elif diff == "3":
            if (diff_var * 2) < length:
                diff_list.append(str(words))
    return random.choice(diff_list)


def start_hangman():
    start = input("Press 'Enter' to start!\n")
    if start == "":
        diff = input(
            "What difficulty would you like? Type a difficulty of 1 - 3 and press 'Enter':  ")
        if diff == "1" or diff == "2" or diff == "3":
            print(word_selector(word_list, diff))
        else:
            print("That's not an option... Difficulties are 1 - 3. Try again.")
            start_hangman()

    else:
        print("What are you doing??? Just press enter!")
        start_hangman()


start_hangman()
```

Comment: No problem! As a general rule, try to separate the role of each function as much as you can: one function picks the words, the other function gets the input etc... Not only it will make finding errors easier, it is also cool and elegant :D